# Can't slice of numpy.float64 value's row from the Dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy

1. ```
       Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume  chikou_span kijun_sen   tenkan_sen
   ```
2. ```
    2022-01-19  3163.850342 3171.158447 3055.212402 3095.825928 3095.825928 13187424144 3057.476074 NaN NaN
   ```

type of chikou_span column is **numpy.float64**

when i use this code below to extract the 3057.476074 value full row form the chikou_span column, it print the empty dataframe

```
df[df['chikou_span']== 3057.476074]

    Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume  chikou_span kijun_sen   tenkan_sen
Date
```

the **3057.476074** is in the colume as you see.

it's only not working with the numpy.flaot64 but for the volume column that is numpy.int64 it would work well to extract the rows of specific value..

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to check an equality when you use real numbers, use [`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html):

```
>>> df[np.isclose(df['chikou_span'], 3057.476074)]

         Open         High          Low        Close          Adj      Close.1       Volume  chikou_span  kijun_sen  tenkan_sen
0  2022-01-19  3163.850342  3171.158447  3055.212402  3095.825928  3095.825928  13187424144  3057.476074        NaN         NaN

>>> df[df['chikou_span'] == 3057.476074]

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Open, High, Low, Close, Adj, Close.1, Volume, chikou_span, kijun_sen, tenkan_sen]
Index: []
```

Why? because you see only a small part of the decimal part. For example, in my example the value is 3057.4760742341 not 3057.476074.

```
>>> df.loc[0, 'chikou_span']
3057.4760742341
```